# Parse an XML as fast as possible

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a VB.Net app that reads a zip file that has an XML file in it.  I need to parse the XML file into row segments, pull one node value out as the application id and send it on it's way to a MS SQL database.  The XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>9243987</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>P30</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>AR</ADMINISTERING_IC>
<APPLICATION_TYPE>5</APPLICATION_TYPE>
<ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
<AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>05/22/2017</AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>
<BUDGET_START>04/01/2017</BUDGET_START>
</row>
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>9243988</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>P30</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>AR</ADMINISTERING_IC>
<APPLICATION_TYPE>5</APPLICATION_TYPE>
<ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
<AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>05/22/2017</AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>
<BUDGET_START>04/01/2017</BUDGET_START>
</row>
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>9243989</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>P30</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>AR</ADMINISTERING_IC>
<APPLICATION_TYPE>5</APPLICATION_TYPE>
<ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
<AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>05/22/2017</AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>
<BUDGET_START>04/01/2017</BUDGET_START>
</row>
</PROJECTS>
```

The file could contain a million records and be close to 100mg in size.  My current code isbelow and could take as long as 8 hours to run for a million records.

My VB code that parses the file is:

```
            If ofdXML.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            stopWatch.Start()
            Dim result As String
            Dim fName As String = ofdXML.FileName
            If fName.EndsWith("zip") Then
                Dim ePath As String = "E:\Downloads\WEEKLY"
                fileName = ExtractArchive(fName, ePath)
                fName = Path.Combine(ePath, fileName)
            End If

            result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fName)
            Dim rdr As New StreamReader(fName)
            While (rdr.Peek >= 0)
                varLine = rdr.ReadLine
                sTag = varLine.Contains("<row>")
                eTag = varLine.Contains("</row>")
                If sTag And eTag Then
                    appLine = varLine
                    If appLine.Contains("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") Then
                        appID = appLine.Substring(Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>"), appLine.IndexOf("/APPLICATION_ID") - Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") - 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf sTag Then
                    v1 = True
                    appLine = varLine
                    If appLine.Contains("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") Then
                        appID = appLine.Substring(Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>"), appLine.IndexOf("/APPLICATION_ID") - Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") - 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf eTag Then
                    appLine = appLine & varLine
                    v1 = False
                ElseIf v1 Then
                    appLine = appLine & varLine
                    If appLine.Contains("<APPLICATION_ID>") Then
                        Dim xi As Integer = appLine.IndexOf("_ID>") + 4
                        appID = appLine.Substring(xi, appLine.IndexOf("/APPLICATION_ID") - (xi + 1))
                    End If
                End If


                If Trim(Len(varLine)) > 0 And appLine.Contains("<row>") And appLine.Contains("</row") And Not varLine.Contains("</PROJECTS>") Then
                    TextBox2.Text = i.ToString
                    TextBox3.Text = appID
                    sb.Append(appID + ",")
                    Application.DoEvents()
                    i += 1
                    ADMIN_Save_To_Database(appLine, appID, result)
                End If
            End While

        End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft's XML parsing tools would be much faster.  [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)  in their example, you could replace "title" with "Application_ID" if you're going this route.

Comment: If you want as fast as possible then use [bulk import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server).

Comment: Make it multi threaded or create tasks...

Comment: My expectation would be that parsing a 100Mb XML file using a professionally-written XML parser should take around 1-2 seconds. The performance of this program will then be dominated by the database update cost rather than the XML parsing.

Comment: `TextBox.Text = someValue` is sooooo slow. A million updates to UI - that's your bottleneck. As well as the saving to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change the code to:

```
            Dim rdr As New StreamReader(fName)
            Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
            xml.Load(rdr)
            Dim DocumentNodes As XmlNodeList = 
            xml.GetElementsByTagName("row")
            For Each xn As XmlNode In DocumentNodes
                Dim example As XmlNode = 
             xn.SelectSingleNode("APPLICATION_ID")
                If example IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim applicationID As String = example.InnerText
                    ADMIN_Save_AuthoringNames(xn.InnerXml, applicationID, result)
                End If
            Next
```

I'll let you know how it runs

Comment: using the code above I was able to cut down the time to about 2 hours but using the code above WITH a BCP it went to less than two minutes.  It seems that my biggest bottleneck was in my saving each record to the database.  THANKS TO EVERYONE

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you investigate actual XML parsing - either into a DOM you can query or SAX you can "listen" to. You're only interested in a specific tag so it should be pretty easy to set up a SAX listener for that tag and ignore everything else.

This should get you started:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_xml_processing.htm

If you insist on sticking with your string parsing look for optimizations. Loops are killer! You don't want to do expensive things inside a loop if you can get away with it.

For example, you calculate the length of "< row >< APPLICATION_ID >" twice for every row (depending on the format). Not only is that expensive, but the result is a constant! Set or calculate it once outside of the loop.

All the .Contains() calls are very expensive. And many of yours are redundant. For example, you check for the existence of "< row >" and "< /row >" near the top of your loop and then you do it again near the bottom of the loop.

In short, your best bet is XML parsing tools. If you don't want to do that, look very carefully thru your code for expensive operations that you can either pull outside of the loop altogether or just do once each time thru.